# SuSE Linux - How to find out previously set passwords of a user

Tags: linux, passwords, recovery, suse

I use SuSE Linux. I have root password.

I have a scenario like this:

A user password is set xxx. and later it is changed to yyy. and it is changed to zzz.

In this scenario, is there any ways to list this user's password set history?

For example, I will write a command like this: passhistory -user user1 and the system will respond like

xxx
yyy
zzz

(passhistory -user user1 is a fictious command which I use to explain my situtaion)

Thanks.

Comment: I hope you'll NEVER EVER be able to list a user's current or historic password - because if you could the password management would be severely broken.

Answer (score 0):

No, as long as you are using [pam](http://www.linux-pam.org/) as your authentication agent (what you probably do) and your pam uses `/etc/shadow` or `/etc/passwd` (what it probably does), you cannot do that. The current password is hashed, and there is virtually no way to un-hash it. The previous passwords are not stored at all.

You could - in theory - install your own authentication module in pam and record the passphrases. But if you do that, ethically, you shouldn't have gotten a root password in the first place...